# udev does not apply rules

Tags: udev

I am having some problem assigning rules from udev.

I have 2 **FTDI232** chips mounted on my board (they are totally 3 but I am interested in 2 of them right now), the kernel manages them with the drivers **ftdi_sio**, names them as **ttyUS0** and **ttyUSB1** and I am applying these rules in order to name them as **usbS1** and **usbS2**:

```
KERNELS=="1-2.1" KERNEL=="ttyUSB0" ATTR{idVendor}=="0403" ATTR{idProduct}=="6001" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" NAME="usbS1"
KERNELS=="1-2.2" KERNEL=="ttyUSB1" ATTR{idVendor}=="0403" ATTR{idProduct}=="6001" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" NAME="usbS2"
```

according to the inormation from **dmesg**

```
[    4.676116] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-omap
[    4.811920] usb 1-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[    4.819244] usb 1-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    4.826965] usb 1-2.1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[    4.831726] usb 1-2.1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[    4.835968] usb 1-2.1: SerialNumber: A101XRTT
[    4.963256] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-omap
[    5.102355] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[    5.109649] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.117370] usb 1-2.2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[    5.122161] usb 1-2.2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[    5.126403] usb 1-2.2: SerialNumber: A101XRTQ

...

[   16.839935] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[   16.848327] ftdi_sio 1-2.1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   16.856781] usb 1-2.1: Detected FT232RL
[   16.977935] usb 1-2.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   16.986785] ftdi_sio 1-2.2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   16.994720] usb 1-2.2: Detected FT232RL
[   17.099914] usb 1-2.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   17.108581] ftdi_sio 1-2.7:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   17.116485] usb 1-2.7: Detected FT232RL
[   17.165710] i2c 2-005c: Driver mt9v032 requests probe deferral
[   17.187561] twl4030_madc 48070000.i2c:twl@48:madc: clk disabled, enabling
[   17.228759] usb 1-2.7: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

But it's not working. I don't know why.

On a older system (with kernel 2.6.34) I was simply applying these rules:

```
KERNELS=="2-2.1" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" NAME="usbS1"
KERNELS=="2-2.2" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb" NAME="usbS2"
```

which works fine on that system, but not on this one I am working on right now (of course with the KERNELS parameters changed).

What's wrong in my rules file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved as so:

```
KERNELS=="1-2.1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", SYMLINK+="usbS0"
KERNELS=="1-2.2", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", SYMLINK+="usbS1"
KERNELS=="1-2.7", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", SYMLINK+="usbS3"
```

The commas and the SYMLINK directives made it work.

Answer (score 1):

It might be one of the following situations:

1. In the rule, you refer directly to these devices by their kernel name (KERNEL=), and maybe the kernel does not call your devices `ttyUSB?`, therefore, the rule does not apply
2. `udev` does not or cannot read the file where you have written your rules.
3. `udev` has already another rule overriding yours for the same devices, applying the `ttyUSB?` name to them.

So, I would suggest that you...

- Check that the **kernel name** of your device is indeed `ttyUSB?`
- Check that no other rule from `udev` makes any other renaming of the same device that could override your rules.
- Check that indeed `udev` loads new rules at all (test with other devices if possible) and that `udev` can read the file where your new rules are... or test that these rules are read by placing them inside an existing rules file.

Answer (score 1):

To help with debugging you can (not as root):

```
udevadm monitor
```

then plug in the device to see what event udev sees. You will probably see that your rules match more than one of the `add` events.

You can convert the device name into a path, eg

```
udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0
```

then give this output path to

```
udevadm test <path>
```

to trace what files udev is reading and the rules it follows.
It doesn't actually run commands and so on, so it is only a hint.